# How can I make debian-gnome slimmer?

Tags: debian, gnome

I've installed debian with gnome desktop, I like using gnome so I don't want to change into other desktop environment such as lxde or fxce. I'm also install the system in a virtual machine, so I want the system to be slimmer.

I want to uninstall programs such as libreoffice, games and some other software, however, it seems that can cause big problems, suppose I want to remove libreoffice: `sudo apt purge libreoffice`. It seems this command will also remove the entire gnome desktop.

**In summary, I'm asking the way to remove the programs I don't want while keep a proper working gnome environment.**

[image]

Comment: [Please do not post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Include command output as text instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing LibreOffice won’t remove the entire GNOME desktop. This used to be the case, but since at least Debian 9 (Stretch), metapackages are handled specially to avoid this scenario. [The `gnome` package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gnome) is a metapackage, as indicated by its presence in [the “metapackages” section](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/metapackages/). When such a package is removed for dependency reasons, as happens when you remove the `libreoffice` package, all the metapackage’s other dependencies are marked as manually installed, which means they won’t be auto-removed.

You can verify this yourself, as follows. The output you show in your question indicates that `apt` will remove `libreoffice` and all its dependencies, and the `gnome` metapackage but none of *its* dependencies. Before you do that, run

```
apt-mark showmanual > ~/manual-pre-removal.txt
```

Now remove `libreoffice` (it’s safe), and run

```
apt-mark showmanual > ~/manual-post-removal.txt
```

Comparing the two files with

```
meld ~/manual-pre-removal.txt ~/manual-post-removal.txt &
```

will show that all the other GNOME packages have been marked as manually installed.

Thus to slim down your GNOME installation in Debian, you can remove the packages corresponding to applications you don’t use. As long as you keep [`gnome-core`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gnome-core) installed, you’ll still have a functional GNOME desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The `gnome` package is a Debian metapackage. Its [description](https://packages.debian.org/stable/gnome) says:

> This metapackage depends on the standard distribution of the GNOME desktop environment, plus a complete range of plugins and other applications integrating with GNOME and Debian, providing the best possible environment to date.

The Gnome metapackage has dependencies on several LibreOffice packages, hence when you remove the `libreoffice` metapackage, the `gnome` metapackage is marked for removal as well. From the `apt` output it looks like no other gnome package, which is not related to LibreOffice, is removed, so removing `gnome` metapackage should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Solution without system reinstall:** You could uninstall the whole `Gnome` desktop by typing `apt-get --purge autoremove gnome`. Afterwards restart the system and it will boot into a command line interface (CLI) without any desktop environment. Then continue at step 3.

---

2. **Solution with system reinstall:** You could reinstall your whole system and hereby avoid automatic installation of a bloated desktop environment by skipping the desktop environment selection prompt of the installer. Afterwards your system will boot into a command line interface (CLI) without any desktop environment. Now continue at step 3.

---

3. When reaching the command line interface (CLI) after reboot, you can setup `Gnome` without any additional accessoires by typing `apt-get install gnome-core`. This will install a clean and lightweight `Gnome` desktop environment without any unwanted bloatware.

Comment: No need to re-install, that’s way overkill!

Comment: @StephenKitt: That is true of course! Thanks for your hint!

Comment: That’s still overkill. For one thing, as alluded to in sebasth’s answer, removing `libreoffice` causes `gnome`’s removal, but because that’s a metapackage, that doesn’t then result in the removal of all its other dependencies. For another, you don’t need to remove all of GNOME to re-install only parts of it; you can mark `gnome-core` as manually installed before removing `gnome`, which avoids all the messing around with rebooting etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a more practical and up-to-date answer, if you just want to reduce the amount of potentially unnecessary software that gets installed with Gnome.

I went through this process and a lot of trial and error approximately two years ago, when installing a fresh Debian 11 (Bullseye). My approach was to find a minimal set of packages that gives me an useful Desktop Environment. If I would feel that something was missing, I prefer to be be forced to install it, instead of having a lot of stuff sitting there eating disk and memory, without ever being used.

First, very important: when installing the OS, ***uncheck*** the desktop environment suggestion and any other additional software to avoid having something installed by default.

When you get the OS running, install Python first. It is a dependency of Gnome, but as Software Engineer and I don't like to have such an important piece of the system as something that was automatically installed. Same goes with `ca-certificates`. This step will avoid accidentally removing these packages on `apt autoremove` for example:

```
$ sudo apt install --no-install-recommends python3 ca-certificates
```

Then moving on to install Gnome itself. This is the subset of packages that worked for me, after many, many broken installations:

```
$ sudo apt install --no-install-recommends \
    gdm3 gnome-session gnome-terminal gnome-control-center gnome-screensaver
```

Some important details:

- One notable missing part is a package to control audio, so you may want to include it if you need audio:

  - It used to be the `pulseaudio` package up to Debian 11;
  - Starting from Debian 12, it was changed to `pipewire`;
  - I read somewhere that `pipewire` is backwards compatible with `pulseaudio`, as long as you install `pipewire-pulse` and do [some configuration](https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire#Using_as_a_substitute_for_PulseAudio.2FJACK.2FALSA). I haven't tried it myself and this usage is considered experimental in Debian 11;
- To be able to control network elements from the settings menu on Gnome, you'll also need `network-manager` (if not yet installed) and `network-manager-gnome`;
- If a window-based file manager is your thing, you may want to include `nautilus`.